# Translating "Intrepid art" to classical latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, names

I need some help verifying that I have translated correctly, (english) -> (classical latin). I have translated "Intrepid art", as in art like drawings or paintings, to: "Artem Intrepidus".

Could someone verify if this is a correct translation and if the ordering is right? I use it as a **name** for social media accounts where I post my drawings.

Answer (score 2):

The form you wrote has errors in agreement of both case and gender.

*Ars intrepida* would be the nominative form since *ars* is feminine.

If you really want accusative, it would be *artem intrepidam*.

It is unclear to me whether *intrepidus -a -um* is really the adjective you want, though.

Comment: I see no immediate problem with *intrepidus*, it does mean "intrepid" (no surprise there) and will be easily recognisable even to beginners. Another possibility would be *impavidus*.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel : Yes, I only meant that it wasn’t clear to me that OP really meant “intrepid”. I’m not familiar with the term “intrepid art”.

Comment: Neither am I, although I have to say, compared to a few mottos and tattoo ideas I have seen on this website, it seems like a pretty ordinary English expression ;-)